# Spring SQL Proper way to use JdbcTemplate.update()

Tags: java, spring

I am following a tutorial found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm). And am trying to follow it with an independent project I am working on called the Ticketing System. So i created this method:

```
public void create(Integer ticketNumber, Date timeOpened, String priorityLevel, String caseOwner) {

    String sql = "insert into user_ticket (ticket_number, opened, priority, case_owner) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplateObject.update(sql, ticketNumber, timeOpened, priorityLevel, caseOwner);

    System.out.println("Created Record Ticket Number = " + ticketNumber + " Time Opened = " + timeOpened + "Priority Level " + 
    priorityLevel + " Case Owner: " + caseOwner);
    return;     
}
```

But the problem is that when I try to use this line:

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(sql, ticketNumber, timeOpened, priorityLevel, caseOwner);
```

I get an error:

```
The method update(String, Object[], int[]) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer, Date, String, String)
```

I understand that the arguments I have provided may not be the right to use the update() method and I am still learning SpringJDBC. Can someone tell me if there is an alternative way of using this method that can satisfy all the arguments I am providing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the the variables in `update()` you should put everything in `Object[]` and then pass it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void create(Integer ticketNumber, Date timeOpened, String priorityLevel, 
                   String caseOwner) {
    String sql = "insert into user_ticket (ticket_number, opened, priority, case_owner) 
                  values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Object[] params = {ticketNumber, timeOpened, priorityLevel, caseOwner};
    jdbcTemplateObject.update(sql, params);

    System.out.println("Created Record Ticket Number = " + ticketNumber + 
                       " Time Opened = " + timeOpened + "Priority Level " + 
                       priorityLevel + " Case Owner: " + caseOwner);
}
```

Comment: @ryekayo Your Welcome! :)